# Why does bootstrap tooltip not work correctly?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I am working with bootstrap in a rails 3.2 app. I included following in the Gemfile

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.1.1'
```

and the following in the assets

assets/javascripts/appliication.js

```
//= require bootstrap
```

my html

```
<input class="btn add-tooltip" title="this is my tooltip" data-placement='bottom' value="myButton" />

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.add-tooltip').tooltip();
     }
</script>
```

Currently my tooltip does not display as the standard popup as on the bootstrap documentation or as this sample
http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/vcr9J/

It now appears delayed on a yellow popup. However, I want it as the standard default as the link above. Am I missing some css inclusions? What else do I need to do for the tooltip to work?

Comment: Well your JavaScript is invalid above

Comment: typo on closing brackets- had it in my main code, still dont work

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript code provided is missing its closing bracket, which should be added like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('.add-tooltip').tooltip();
    });
</script>
```

Once added, taking your code snippet and pasting it into JSBin along with a reference to jQuery and Bootstrip gives exactly what is expected, with the default black Bootstrap tooltip:
http://jsbin.com/danilodo/1/

If you're seeing a different color tooltip then something else you're not sharing with us is overriding the styling.

Comment: Your JS Fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/vcr9J/, also displays as a black tooltip using Chrome, FireFox, Safari and IE11.